# JQuery form with validate keeps refreshing page - no post-request send

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, summernote

I'm struggeling with an ajax-form on a bootstrap webpage which is pretty simple (I thought).

Here the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aptwd1wb/2/

As you can see here I defined this validation + submit handling:

```js
 $('#formular').validate({
  ignore: [],
  rules: {
    headlinetext: {
      minlength: 3,
      maxlength: 100,
      required: true
    },
    image: {
      accept: "image/*",
      required: true,
    },
    select: {
      required: true,
    },
    summernoteinput: {
      summernoteMinimumSize: true,
      summernoteRequired: true,
    },

  },
  highlight: function(element) {
    var id_attr = "#" + $(element).attr("id") + "1";
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
  },
  unhighlight: function(element) {
    var id_attr = "#" + $(element).attr("id") + "1";
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    $(id_attr).removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
  },
  errorElement: 'span',
  errorClass: 'help-block',
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.length) {
      error.insertAfter(element);
    } else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
    }
  },
  messages: {
    select: {
      required: 'Required'
    },
    image: {
      accept: 'NO!'
    }
  },

  submitHandler: function(error) {
    var file = $('#image')[0].files[0];
    $.post(
      'http://test.com' + "/myFile.php", {
        plant: $('#select').val(),
        headline: $('#headlinetext').val(),
        body: $('#summernote').summernote('code'),
        image: file
      }
    );

    return false;
  },

});
```

The problem is, that the form is validated correctly, but when pressing the submit-button and everything is valid, the submitHandler forces the page to a reload. I used 'return false;' to avoid this, but nothing changed.

After the refresh I got an new URL like :

```
index.html?select=02&headlinetext=ghjhg+jhg+g+jhg+&image=some.PNG&files=&summernoteinput=
```

I just want to submit the input by ajax to a backend service and after that show a success message.

I really don't know whats wrong with this code.

---

As a bonus question: As you may can see in the console, the summernote plugin triggers many errors like :

[image]

Why?.... Just why? 
Googled about an hour and didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: Well, there is no way to test the submitHandler and help you, since the Fiddle seems incomplete. Can you please add the submit button and submitHandler code in it.

Comment: this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/aptwd1wb/2/ -  it seems complete to me, the submitHandler starts in line 77 of the code in the fiddle. But i sure can just paste some more code here directly

Comment: Does changing your type="submit" to type="button" resolves your issue ?

Comment: jQuery Validate `submitHandler` is not working at all... if the `$.post()` was firing then the page would not be refreshing.  Commenting out this line resolves your issue:  `body: $('#summernote').summernote('code'),`

Comment: In other words, you cannot call the `.summernote()` method from within the `.validate()` method.